# Add array to markergroups

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, marker

I have variabel like this for storing marker:

```
var markerGroups = {"1": [], "2": [], "3": [], "4": [], "5": [], "6": [], "7": [], "8": [], "9": [], "10": [], "11": [], "12": [], "13": [], "14": [], "15": [], "16": [], "17": [], "18": [], "19": [], "20": [],};
```

it works perfectly. Storing marker with type and hide/show marker. But I wanna dynamic like:

```
var ar = `<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['id_jenis']) ?>;`

var markerGroups = {for/do/while ar}
```

How can i do this?
I am still trying but not working.
Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION['id_jenis']`?

Comment: primary key id_jenis. I get it from query. It give me result '1,2,3,4,5,6 and till last

Comment: you can do it like this: for (var key in markerGroups) { var array = markerGroups[key] } but it will go through elements on alphabetical ascending order.

Comment: let me try :). Thanks

Comment: Why is `markerGroups` an object? If all the keys are consecutive numbers, why not make it an array?

Comment: Ups, still not working.

Comment: @Barmar : I get the code from google and other, it works. I have 20 type of object. So i write it in markerGroups:{"1": [], "2": [], exct};. Now I have 17 type of objects. My code not effective and efficen anymore I think. So i wanna make it dynamically.

Comment: _i wanna make it dynamically_. You can fill in an array dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var markerGroups = {};
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    markerGroups[i] = [];
}
```